# How can I setup a dev copy of EE before license purchase?

Tags: development, license

I have built over 70 EE sites in thej last few years.  I noticed now in EE 2.8+ that it is now required to enter a license number even on a local copy.  Is there a new method to allow us to build and test before getting the license?  Maybe like using a .dev or .local domain extension or something?  I have many client licneses I can use if needed, but I do not like that option.  The reason we like to build a bit of the CMS in advance is that we typically we demo it with a client to see if the like the way it works for basic editing.  What do you all do now for your local dev copies of EE?  Is it possible to get a dev license?

Comment: Most people I know have a base install that is ready to go and they duplicate the files and database when starting a new project. They also perform and test upgrades of EE (and add-ons) against this default install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start building before our licenses are purchased. We just put in a random number until we actually get the real license. EE doesn't currently do an authorization call on install to validate your license. We use stuff like: 1234-1234-1234-1234.

Comment: That is awesome.  I will do that on next install.  We have 5 sites in development and we typically purchase at site launch.

Comment: That doesn't mean that the people at ellis labs won't be adding that "feature" soon. If they do, you might need to either just buy the license or use the free version and upgrade later. Also, be sure to mark this question as answered.